# Axios - parse Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, api, parsing, axios

I want to parse data from an axios request on typescript

I got two interfaces

```
interface Department{
    code: string;
    name: string;
    country: string;
}

interface User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    departments: Department[];
}
```

I got an endpoint which returns data like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Estonia",
        "email": "email",
        "phone": 12345,
        "weight": "60kg",
        "country": "US",
        "departments": [
            {
              "code": 1,
              "name": "depto 1",
              "country": "US"
            },
            {
              "code": 2,
              "name": "depto 2",
              "country": "FR"
            }
        ]
        [...]
    }
]
```

The endpoint retrieves a lot of data which I don't need, I just want to retrieve attributes I've defined on the interface, is this possible?

I have tried this, but I got all attributes

```
axios.get<User[]>('http://localhost/users').then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(typeof data, data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> The endpoint retrieves a lot of data which I don't need, I just want to retrieve attributes I've defined on the interface, is this possible?

If you use it the way you have at the moment `axios.get<User[]>` then you will only be able to read the properties that exist on the `User` interface.

The objects will have more properties but you will not be able to read / write them from TypeScript (without unsafe type assertions) so what you have is what I would do and not worry about the excess runtime properties.

Comment: Thank you. Basically what I want to do is modify the properties I've defined in the interface and reply with only those. So far, I'm getting all properties. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can with `tapi.js` - it's a lightweight package just for this purpose.

Read [the documentation](https://tapi.js.org) here.